# How to properly append to an array using Dgraph GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, graph-databases, dgraph

I'm trying to spin up Dgraph, but appears as though to add a node to an array of nodes using the GraphQL api requires an unnecessary amount of work if I understand it correctly:

I have the following simplified schema:

```
type User @secret(field: "password") {
    account: String! @id
    email: String! @search(by: [hash])
    extension: String! @search(by: [hash])
    phone: String! @search(by: [hash])
    hasCreated: [Transaction]! @hasInverse(field: from)
    hasReceived: [Transaction]! @hasInverse(field: to)
}

type Transaction {
    id: ID!
    type: TransactionType! @search(by:[terms])
    amount: Float! 
    assetCode: String! @search(by:[terms])
    to: User!
    from: User!
    initiatedAt: DateTime! @search(by:[hash])
    completedAt: DateTime @search(by:[hash])
    status: Status!
}
```

To me, it appears as though to add a node to the `User`'s `hasCreated` or `hasReceived` fields would require me to pull the entire array, append a new `Transaction` to the array and then use an `updateUser` mutation to complete the update. But the `updateUser` mutation would require me to get ***all*** the `Transactions` and ***all*** `Users` attached to these transactions and so on.

Example trying to retrieve an entire user object:

```
query {
                getUser(id:"%s"){
                    account
                    email
                    extension
                    phone
                    hasCreated {
                        id
                        type
                        amount
                        assetCode
                        to {
                            ...
                        }

                    }
                    hasReceived {
                        id
                        type
                        amount
                        assetCode
                        to {
                            ...
                        }

                    }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there another way to append to arrays or update objects using the GraphQL api without having to retrieve whole objects?